# Use my dataframe in a loop so It can be use in a Json process

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the next code

```
payload = json.dumps({
  "phones": [
    {
      "phone": "593 999999999"
    },
    {
      "phone": "593 000000000"
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ********',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

The responde message I´ts:

```
`{"summary":{"total":2,"valid":1,"invalid":1},"numbers":[{"valid":true,"error":null,"input":"+593 997178570","phone":"+59399999999","wid":"593997178570@c.us","kind":"mobile","country":"EC","countryPrefix":593,"formats":{"local":"997178570","nationaal":"099 999 9999","international":"+593 99 999 9999"}},{"valid":false,"error":"The phone number is not WhatsApp compatible","input":"+593 000000000","phone":"+593 000000000","wid":null,"kind":"unknown","country":"EC","countryPrefix":593,"formats":{"nationaal":"+593 000000000","international":"+593 000000000"}}]}`
```

And then I do this.

```
data = response.json()

aux=pd.DataFrame(data['numbers'])
resultado=aux[['phone','valid']]
```

So I already know how to put that responde into a dataframe that It´s the purpose of this.

So my question is this, how can I use that process with a dataframe simple as this

| Number |
| --- |
| 593987654321 |
| 593987654322 |
| 593987654323 |
| 593987654324 |

It´s there a way to put that dataframe into a loop so I can use my Json process.
Or to convert my dataframe into a dictionary?. I have no experience working with Json.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there response from server and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC, you can export `Number` column to list of dictionaries with `.to_dict('records')`.

```py
payload = {"phones": df[['Number']].rename(columns={'Number':'phone'}).to_dict('records')}
```

```
print(payload)

{'phones': [{'phone': 593987654321}, {'phone': 593987654322}, {'phone': 593987654323}, {'phone': 593987654324}]}
```